# EFCore EnsureCreated() run command after table creation

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, timescaledb

So I'm pretty new to EFCore (straight into 5.0 preview, because why not), and enjoying all the fluent configuration side of things. The whole `IEntityTypeConfiguration<>` concept really helps in making the Entities agnostic to the backing DB (as opposed to using attributes on the entities themselves).

I generate my whole database using `DbContext.Database.EnsureCreated()` in my **Startup.cs**. It's currently backed by SQLite while I'm playing around, but would like to eventually move to PostgreSQL with the TimescaleDB extension.

The thing is, when using TimescaleDB, I would need to issue a `create_hypertable()` immediately after creating the table itself.

What's the best way to issue a command after table creation?

- Right after `EnsureCreated()`, using `ExecuteSqlRaw()`? That means *all* the tables have been created before the SQL is executed. I would prefer having it as close to the table creation as possible.
- Somewhere inside the `DbContext`?
- In my `IEntityTypeConfiguration<>`?
- or somewhere else?

Thanks!

Comment: Use [migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and modify the generated migration to directly issue your custom stuff right after creating the table. That way, your custom command runs _as part_ of the migration itself.

Comment: Like poke, my preference is also to create "migrations", then manually "update database"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep using `context.Database.EnsureCreated()`, then running your own script (e.g. by executing `context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw()`) after the call is the way to go here.

> That means all the tables have been created before the SQL is executed. I would prefer having it as close to the table creation as possible.

There shouldn't be any downsides to this as far as I can see, so you are not gaining anything by moving the `create_hypertable()` call closer to another table (if you disagree, please elaborate why this is the case).

---

If you *really* want to move the call near another command for some reason, than you could implement a `DbCommandInterceptor`. You could then parse the command text for a specific `CREATE TABLE` statement or something and then issue your own statement. (If you want to go that route, post a comment and I update this answer with some code.)

---

In case you switch from using `context.Database.EnsureCreated()` to migrations, you can use the `Sql()` method to inject your own statements:

```cs
public partial class MyMigration : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.Sql("SELECT create_hypertable('conditions', 'time');")
    }
}
```

---

Maybe you can elaborate a bit, *why* you feel the need to move the `create_hypertable()` calls closer to their tables.

---

If you just care about having the `create_hypertable()` calls close in the C# code, but not necessarily in the generated SQL code, then introducing a custom attribute (or an interface) and a method to apply the hypertable to all entities that have properties decorated with this attribute (or implement this interface) might be good enough:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class HypertableColumnAttribute : Attribute
{
}

public static class DbContextExtensions
{
    public static void ApplyHypertables(this Context context)
    {
        var entityTypes = context.Model.GetEntityTypes();

        foreach (var entityType in entityTypes)
        {
            foreach (var property in entityType.GetProperties())
            {
                if (property.ClrType.GetCustomAttribute(
                    typeof(HypertableColumnAttribute)) != null)
                {
                    var tableName = entityType.GetTableName();
                    var columnName = property.GetColumnName();

                    context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated(
                        $"SELECT create_hypertable({tableName}, {columnName});");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class IceCream
{
    public int IceCreamId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [HypertableColumn]
    public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<IceCream> IceCreams { get; set; }

    /// ...
}

internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        using var context = new Context();

        context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        context.ApplyHypertables();

        var iceCreams = context.IceCreams
            .OrderBy(i => i.IceCreamId)
            .ToList();
        
        Debug.Assert(iceCreams.Count == 2);
    }
}
```

In case you want to keep your model classes clean of any database specific attributes, you can use annotations instead. The idea is basically the same, but annotations are EF Core metadata and can be defined as part of an `IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>` implementation using the `HasAnnotation()` method:

```cs
public static class DbContextExtensions
{
    public static void ApplyHypertables(this Context context)
    {
        var entityTypes = context.Model.GetEntityTypes();

        foreach (var entityType in entityTypes)
        {
            foreach (var property in entityType.GetProperties())
            {
                var isHypertableColumn = property.FindAnnotation(MyAnnotationNames.Hypertable)?.Value;
                if ((bool)(isHypertableColumn ?? false))
                {
                    var tableName = entityType.GetTableName();
                    var columnName = property.GetColumnName();

                    context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated(
                        $"SELECT create_hypertable({tableName}, {columnName});");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class MyAnnotationNames
{
    public const string Prefix = "MyPrefix:";
    public const string Hypertable = Prefix + "Hypertable";
}

public class IceCream
{
    public int IceCreamId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}

public class IceCreamConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<IceCream>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<IceCream> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(e => e.UpdatedAt)
            .HasAnnotation(MyAnnotationNames.Hypertable, true);
        
        builder.HasData(
            new IceCream {IceCreamId = 1, Name = "Vanilla"},
            new IceCream {IceCreamId = 2, Name = "Chocolate"});
    }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<IceCream> IceCreams { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        => modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new IceCreamConfiguration());

    /// ...
}

internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        using var context = new Context();

        context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        context.ApplyHypertables();

        var iceCreams = context.IceCreams
            .OrderBy(i => i.IceCreamId)
            .ToList();
        
        Debug.Assert(iceCreams.Count == 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers for that. I don't *need* it to be close to the table; I just like the idea of having definitions in a single logical place for each table (and currently they're pretty self-contained in the `EntityTypeConfiguration`). So yeah, while I understand it can be executed literally anytime after the table has been created, I like having one particular file that tells me everything to know about that table.

Comment: Btw, thanks for the migration suggestion. I'll get my head around that. And maybe keep the hypertable command in the EntityTypeConfiguration as a static (to keep it next to the rest of the definitions), and call it from the migrations.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your reasoning. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Is there a built-in way for custom attributes to be applied using the Fluent API in the Entity configurator? I would rather my Entities decoupled and clean of implementation attributes.

Comment: Actually, considering the time-series nature of the data is intrinsic to the entity, I could still have them as attributes, but with a more generic name. E.g. `[TimeSeriesDimension]` and let it be handled as a hypertable when in timescale, or something else if I decide to change the underlying database. Thanks for the ideas!

Comment: Using custom attributes is one way of handling this. If you want to keep the information in your `EntityTypeConfiguration`, you can set an annotation there as part of the model definition, that you then handle in `ApplyHypertables` instead of the custom attribute. This would keep your actual model classes clean. If you need some sample code to get you started, I can post the sample code with this variation as well.

Comment: You've gone above and beyond what I expected to get out of this; but I would most certainly appreciate an example code on defining this in the Configurator. Might also benefit other people coming in here looking for examples of the different ways to implement custom table behaviours.

Comment: No problem. I added an annotation based approach to the answer.

Comment: Thanks heaps. Last time I touched it, EF was in its infancy. I can see it has matured so much in 10 years.